# Getting the following error when trying to run a hive query

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

```
hive> select count(1) from stage;
```

> **FAILED:** RuntimeException java.net.ConnectException: Call From server1/ipaddress to server2:8020 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; 
>   For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused

I am new to hive. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the reason for this error, 
I executed the netstat on the ports 80, 2181, 3181 and found the following, 
netstat -nlp | grep 3181
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3181                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      4106/PatrolAgent

The reason for the issue was due to system kernel error. The port was bound already and not released, so the processes were dead but port was not released.
Then killed the process 4106....
Then it started working...

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your Job tracker is down.
You can check that using this command:

```
sudo jps
```